# French SF novel: isolationist Europe, mimicking insects

Tags: story-identification

Bit of a long shot this.

In the mid-90s I lived in France for a bit and read a particular SF novel which has stuck in my mind. It was a near-future scenario where Europe had become extremely isolationist, to the point that outsiders were not allowed in at all; there was an impassable barrier around the border and automatic (DNA?) scanners everywhere inside.

The protagonist was an agent for Britain, which was outside the barrier; he finds a way to sneak into Europe and (he believes) fool the scanners, although this turns out not to work fully.

Other things I remember:

- there was some kind of space-stretching technology which was used to make living in tiny apartments more bearable;
- at some point the agent gets taken to a prison camp where he encounters a scientist who has been training some microscopic insects to mimic objects at the molecular level; the insects copy the agent's son, and he prefers the copy to the original;
- at the end the space-stretching thing goes wrong in some way which affects all of Europe, leaving one character as somehow the "god" of the whole area.

It was a very weird book, and I think my copy was missing the last few pages, so I never learned how it ended.

Comment: Odd sounding book. I have very little insight into French science fiction, so I'm not going to be able to help at all. But I'm very curious about the possible answers—and if there's a translation. Come to think of it, my wife speaks French, so she might be interested in reading it in the original.

Comment: I assume that the book was written in French? Do you happen to remember whether the author's name sounded French?

Comment: It was in French, yes. I don't remember anything about the author name, but the whole thing had a very Euro-centric feel so I'm pretty sure it wasn't translated from anything else.

Comment: _where Europe had become extremely isolationist..._ Entire Europe or individual country/countries (France)? And isn't Britain a part of Europe? Or you meant mainland Europe?

Comment: Yes, mainland only; I think it was basically the EC (as it then was) minus Britain. In particular I remember that Switzerland was excluded, the barrier went all the way round the country and the only way in was by air.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost certainly *[Cette chère humanité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cette_ch%C3%A8re_humanit%C3%A9)* by Philippe Curval (1976, translated in 1981 as *Brave Old World*). It is a part of the book series *L'Europe après la pluie*.

Automated translation of the summary from the wikipedia article in French:

> For the past twenty years, Marcom, once the Europe of the Common
> Market, has been cut off from the rest of the world and withdrawn
> behind high walls bristling with impenetrable defenses.
>
> However, a cry for help has managed to penetrate the wall, informing
> the rest of the planet that a formidable danger threatens it.

The story also features slowing-time devices in people's apartments; and one of the characters is composed of tiny insects capable of taking any form.

If you want more details about the story, it's difficult to find online reviews about it in English - I just found [this one](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/a/philippe-curval/brave-old-world/):

> In the late 21st century, Marcom (a high-tech, 13-state Common
> Market), hiding itself behind impenetrable energy barriers, has become
> an utterly rigid, self-absorbed, nostalgia-sodden police state: it's
> secretly controlled by the Slow Time Company, which markets devices
> that stretch time (thus providing longevity) and space [...]
>
> [...] when the outside world discovers that Marcom's spacetime warps are
> threatening to drop the entire Earth out of its continuum, attorney
> Belgacen Attia is sent to penetrate Marcom's deadly neurological
> barriers and destroy the slow time network.

Otherwise, you'll mostly find resources in French about it, like this [short review](https://resf.hypotheses.org/5241) or this [academic analysis](https://journals.openedition.org/resf/524) of the novel, which mentions the mimicking insects (automated translation):

> Glycine, a telepathic simulacrum of a young woman made up of tiny
> insects capable of giving her every conceivable shape, probes Sahel's
> unconscious to find a memory left there by his father.

This [other review](https://leschroniquesduchroniqueur.wordpress.com/2022/05/23/cette-chere-humanite-de-philippe-curval/) in French gives more details about the mimicking insects and the Glycine character (again, automated translation):

> Glycine is a collective intelligence created by artist and scientist
> Ferenczi, taking the form of a young girl composed of a gigantic swarm
> of "pulvis mutabilis", microscopic insects capable of imitating any
> life form whose intelligence and body appear more powerful than that
> of a human. She thus surpasses the life form she is supposed to
> imitate thanks to the multitude of individuals that make up her, which
> may make her a posthuman, since her humanity is called into question
> by the characters, but also by her abilities, which surpass standard
> humanity.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This does sound promising, but you could improve your answer by including more details (from reviews or your own memory) that tie this work to the details of the question.

Comment: @DavidW Sure. My bad. I wasn't sure how to quote sources in French, in doubt I used an automated translation.

Comment: Automatic translations are fine as long as you disclaimer it. :)

Comment: Wow, this is definitely it. Thanks for replying after all this time. Looks like my memory was mostly accurate: I just misremembered whose son Sahel was (Cessieu, head of the stretching company who becomes the god, not Belgacen, the agent).